# How are Asgardians able to speak English?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, asgardians

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, Thor and other Asgardians don't appear to have visited the Earth for a considerable amount of time, certainly not after the English language was created.

Since there are have been no "recent" interactions between the humans and Asgardians, how are they able to understand and speak English?

Comment: Translator microbes / Universal translator?

Comment: Heimdall is able to see all of the different realms. The Asgardians therefore have some method of contact.

Comment: @Richard They are superior. Why would they use so-called inferior's (human's) language?

Comment: I think the easiest answer is probably going to come from "Your ancestors called it magic, but you call it science. I come from a land where they are one and the same." aka **translator microbes** http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslatorMicrobes

Comment: I don't know about the Marvel Universe, but in the actual mythologies, your first paragraph would be incorrect: the gods of Asgard visited earth many times during the Viking ages, which were well after English was considered a language of its own and called English (well, Ænglisc). (And English wasn't ‘created’; like all other natural languages, it just developed over time.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I assume that by "created," Dilip means "came to be."

Comment: @Shokhet Yes. I meant the development over time.

Comment: Don't you mean how are humans able to speak Asgardian?

Comment: @LCIII No. It's the Asgardians who come to the Earth first.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the comics, this is thanks to something they call:

> **All-Tongue** or **AllSpeak**: "When Thor speaks with the All-Tongue anyone who hears him will hear him speak their native language in their hearts" (from Thor's wiki page)

In the absence of further information, it seems likely to assume the same is true of Marvel Movie Asgardians as well - though given the whole 'Our magic is just extremely advanced science' instead of 'we are actually godly beings' angle, it's also likely to assume that the AllSpeak ability stems from something different - the "tech" behind Movie-verse Allspeak might very well be some kind of translator microbes (or an invisible wearable computer "aura" perhaps)

<sub>(I knew of the All-Tongue idea as 'general knowledge' but I'm having hard time finding references to it, outside of that one place in wiki (which cites *Thor #617*) so I'm now unsure how common this idea really is. If anyone has better references please feel free to add.)</sub>

Comment: Asguardians are not the only alien race that speaks English. Do they all speak in All-tongue?

Comment: +1 Most of the species know Earth languages but it is canon that Asgardians have All-speak that translates any language to theirs and theirs to any language.

Comment: Is there any "AllHear"? If a random guy speaks in his language, Thor can hear it as his own language?

Answer (score -6):

They are the keepers of the universe. And study the places they rule over. So that explains why they might have the knowledge of English.

As far as why that seems to be the language they always use...... No clue.