# Do all characters have a universal translator?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Throughout the Marvel films, and to some extent the comics as well, we see lots of different species of creature all communicating in the same language, English (for the English version of everything) except for Groot.

Previous answers have covered both the [Asgardians](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64102/58193) (their language is understood by all and they understand all) and specifically [Star Lord](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66345/58193), he has a translator in his neck.

But how does this work for characters who don't have a translator for instance the humans of Earth who are not Star Lord are able to easily understand non human, non Asgardian characters with no effort?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Kree certainly have access to the translator technology and so at least Starforce would use them. We see this when Vers lands on Earth and talks to the security guard.

> **Vers:** Hi, I'm Vers. Kree Starforce. Is this C-53? Do you understand me? Is my universal translator working?
>
> <sub>*Captain Marvel*</sub>

You've got to remember that a lot of the galaxy, at least what we see, are space faring and high tech, far more advanced than Earth and humans. Because most are space faring it would make sense for them to have and use universal translators as we see in the two known instances: Carol and Peter.

It would be a necessity when visiting another planet/species to use a translator so you can communicate with them. That doesn't mean people who stay on their own planet are using one i.e. those on Earth. But as we see from the above quote from Vers, the translator works both ways and so it wouldn't be needed for both parties to use one.