# Why do the Wakandans speak English?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018, black-panther-wakanda-forever

In the MCU, the inhabitants of the nation of Wakanda largely speak English (although other languages, such as Xhosa, Zulu, and Igbo, are also heard). It's not simply that they are cosmopolitan and happen to *know* English: this is the case even when people are speaking among themselves, not foreigners. That said, in real life, countries where English is the dominant everyday language tend to be either the UK or former colonies of the UK, for obvious reasons. Wakanda was highly insular, never colonized, and quite independently wealthy, which would seem to disfavor most reasons to adopt English as an everyday language.

Obviously, out-of-universe, most of the actors were American, and most American audiences would not understand the other Wakandan languages (to say nothing of a conlang). However, *in-universe*, why is English the predominant language in Wakanda?

Comment: wait till you hear what language the Greek Gods are speaking

Comment: Related: [How are Asgardians able to speak English?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64102/7957)  | [Is everyone in Guardians of the Galaxy speaking English?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66345/7957) | [Do all characters have a universal translator?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/226955/7957)

Comment: Because it is a [movie-film](https://www.critique-film.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Borat-2-Affiche.jpg). Jagshemesh.

Answer (score 20):

They aren't speaking English, they're speaking Wakandan, as confirmed in [this interview](https://ew.com/article/2016/05/05/black-panther-language-wakanda-xhosa/) with Entertainment Weekly. We're hearing them in English because it's convenient for the audience not to have to read subtitles and for the actors not to have to speak extensively in an unfamiliar language. This is referred to in films as a ['translation convention'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_convention).

> Apart from a handful of terms, T’Challa’s fictional African nation had
> no differentiated language in the Marvel canon. **But its people
> wouldn’t exactly be speaking English, since part of Wakanda’s lore was
> that the technologically advanced land had never been conquered.**
>
> Chadwick Boseman’s character does speak English throughout the movie
> to other English-speakers, of course. He’s a statesman, and presumably
> knows many other languages, too. But **for intimate scenes between
> T’Challa, the prince of Wakanda, and his father, King T’Chaka,
> directors Joe and Anthony Russo felt the two men should communicate in
> a native tongue, one that rose up from the continent itself, free of
> interference from outsiders.**
>
> “The language we used for Wakandan is called Xhosa,” Joe Russo tells
> EW. “John Kani, the actor who plays T’Challa’s father in the movie,
> speaks the language and taught it to Chadwick. It’s spoken by 7.6
> million people in South Africa.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Black Panther language: Where Captain America: Civil War found the words of Wakanda](https://ew.com/article/2016/05/05/black-panther-language-wakanda-xhosa/)</sup></sub>

Comment: It sounds as if that article is saying that as of *Civil War*, the chronologically earliest film and one that did not focus on Wakanda, T'Challa and T'Chaka *actually spoke Xhosa* among themselves. Does it indicate that in later movies, the English spoken among Wakandans is supposed to be a translation convention for Xhosa? There is also actual Xhosa in the later films.

Comment: @Adamant - My take is that when there are people around who speak English, they're speaking English. When there's nobody around except Wakandans, they speak Wakandan. That makes perfect sense and is what would happen in reality too.

Comment: It does, but do you have a reference establishing this for later films? For instance, in *Black Panther*, we hear both English *and* Xhosa spoken in Wakanda. Are they *both* supposed to be Xhosa (or even a fictional "Wakandan")?

Comment: [How IsiXhosa Became The Official Language of Wakanda](https://www.okayafrica.com/black-panther-isixhosa-language/). *Kani was playing King T'Chaka..."We had this scene where I had to do a conversation...I was supposed to say to him, 'I miss you, my son, I haven't seen you in a very long time.'... I asked the directors, 'Why am I speaking English? He's my son we're from Wakanda.' And the directors asked, 'What would you say?' I said 'Unqabile nyana, ndikugqibele kudala.' ... Chadwick responded ...'Ndiyaxolisa baba.' ... The language was then adopted as the official language of Wakanda.*

Comment: Subtitles? I don't go to a film so that I can read a damn book!

Comment: I agree that your interpretation seems most plausible, but all those sources seem to just establish that Xhosa is actually spoken in *Civil War* (which we already know) and that it represents the official language of Wakanda (but not necessarily that the "English" that people seem to be speaking is actually Xhosa). Without some statement or proof that the English is actually Xhosa, we don't know that the directors didn't change their mind about the worldbuilding before *Black Panther* and say (for instance) "people speak English because it borders Uganda" (which it does on the maps).

Comment: I suppose that Wakandan is a fictional language, and both Xhosa and English are used to stand in for it as called for by the director for verisimilitude and convenience. It would be strange for Wakandans to speak a language that is native to a region thousands of miles to the south, but most world audiences would not know the difference. Presumably, the numerous South African speakers of Xhosa were as pleased to hear their own language spoken in the theater as Kenyan speakers of Kikuyu were to hear their native tongue in _Return of the Jedi_.

Comment: @Adamant in a more science fiction sense I remember for Babylon 5 jms explaining the Centauri are really speaking Centauri between themselves just like WWII film Germans don't speak English between themselves.  If there's an artistic reason a movie will switch to native language mode for a special scene - but for the most part subtitles are inconvenient for both actors and audiences.  Ironically this happens so much for Klingon that one is forced to conclude the universal translators are polite and don't translate klingon when the speaker really wants the message to be especially Klingon.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - This will forever be the example I point to; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEvwbxcRaCQ

Comment: @Valorum: Vikings (the TV show) is an interesting example too. In every scene, there is a "main" language based on the main conversation taking place. If two Vikings are conversing, they do so in (our) English, and e.g. an English monk entering the scene will be speaking Old English. But if there's two monks are conversing, they do so in (our) English, and e.g. a Viking entering the scene will be speaking old Norse. There are cases where the "main" language shifts _within the same scene_ as characters leave/enter the main focus of the scene, and it is surprisingly intuitive to follow.

Comment: @Valorum: I'm pointing it out because it's the same principle as The Hunt For Red October, where the actual language shifts into English after a few lines; but in an upgraded version as it shifts more dynamically.